# why select count() so slow with left join

Tags: mysql, performance, count, left-join

Here is my sql:

```
select count(*) 
from goods g 
left join goods_policy s 
      on g.com_uid = s.com_uid
     AND g.goods_uid = s.goods_uid 
WHERE g.com_uid = '123'
```

There are only 2000 records in each table, but it costs more than 4 seconds.
The explain is below:

```
1   SIMPLE  g   ref AK_GOOD_CODE,GOODS_IDX_COM,GOODS_IDX_STATUS GOODS_IDX_COM   98  const   1272    Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  s   ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 98  biz_1.g.COM_UID 2   Using where; Using index
```

Table goods_policy has three fields, com_uid, goods_uid and policy_uid while table goods has com_uid , goods_uid and other fields about goods itself.

if I use inner join, it only costs 0.01 seconds with the same explain result.

Why left join costs so much time and How can I improve this sql.

Edit:
Here is the rows in both tables:

```
select count(*) from goods;2827
select count(*) from GOODS_POLICY; 2729
```

And Here is the index :

```
goods   0   PRIMARY 1   GOODS_UID   A   2544                BTREE       
goods   0   AK_GOOD_CODE    1   COM_UID A   14              BTREE       
goods   0   AK_GOOD_CODE    2   GOODS_CODE  A   2544                BTREE       
goods   0   AK_GOOD_CODE    3   STATUS  A   2544            YES BTREE       
goods   1   GOODS_IDX_COM   1   COM_UID A   14              BTREE       

goods_policy    0   PRIMARY 1   COM_UID A   1364                BTREE       
goods_policy    0   PRIMARY 2   POLICY_UID  A   2729                BTREE       
goods_policy    0   PRIMARY 3   GOODS_UID   A   2729                BTREE
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN is going to include all rows from `goods`, INNER will only include the rows that have matches in `goods_policy`. They are different queries, and I am guessing the `count` is much larger with the LEFT one.

Comment: With a left join, "Count" will surely just return the count of records in the goods table - the join makes no different?

Comment: yes, but there are only 2000 rows in each table, how can left join be so slow.

Comment: You can probably speed up both queries by indexing `com_uid` and `goods_uid` in both tables. ...also, are the times reproducible. With that amount of data, it is very easy for the results to have been cached.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I add the table size and index.  it costs more than 4 seconds to get the result.

Comment: Also, what datatype are all the fields. JOINing on long VARCHAR's is a lot more demanding than INT types; though that still should not cause the difference. Have you confirmed times are consistent on repeated executions of both queries?

Comment: No, the `COUNT(*)` is done _after_ the `JOIN`.  And, with `LEFT`, there may be a lot more rows.  So, back to the question -- which count do you want?

Answer (score 0):

remove where clause and add it to join then it will perform that slect before the join and it will join only the selected set of results

```
select count(*) from goods g left join 
 goods_policy s on s.com_uid = '123' AND 
g.goods_uid = s.goods_uid and g.com_uid = '123'
```

Comment: MySQL is usually smart enough to use such conditions from the where clauses before actually joining.

Comment: yes thats true but in some case we have to explicitly say it. please try this and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try with a composite index

```
CREATE TABLE goods (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (com_uid ),
    INDEX goods (com_uid , goods_uid )
);

CREATE TABLE goods_policy (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (goods_uid),
    INDEX goods_policy (com_uid , goods_uid )
);
```

After that also try with @Mahesh Sugestion

```
select count(*) 
from goods g 
left join goods_policy s 
      on g.com_uid = s.com_uid
     AND g.goods_uid = s.goods_uid 
     AND g.com_uid = '123'
```

Comment: Moving the `WHERE` into `ON`, when you have a `LEFT JOIN`, changes the meaning.  Either get rid of `LEFT` or move the 123 back to `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange, in `goods_policy`:

```
PRIMARY KEY(com_uid, goods_uid, policy_uid)
```

That will make the `JOIN` more efficient.

(But it does not address whether you are counting the right thing, nor whether `LEFT` is needed.  I strongly suspect one or both are wrong.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` before discussing this further.

Answer (score 0):

By adding indexs on com_uid, policy_uid and goods_uid, problem solved.